# Calculations inside window function in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a dataset of sales. To summarize, the structure is

| client_id | date_purchase |
| --- | --- |

There might be several purchases done by the same customer on different dates. There can also be several purchases done on the same date (by different or the same customer).

My goal is to **get the number of customers, for any given day, that made 2 or more purchases between that day and 90 days prior**.

That is, the expected output is

| date_purchase | number_of_customers |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-12-19 | 200 |
| 2022-12-18 | 194 |

(...)

Please note this calculates, for any given date, the number of customer with 2+ purchases **between that date and 90 days prior.**

I know it has something to do with a window function. But so far I have not found a way to calculate, for every window of 90 days, how many customers have done 2+ purchases.

I've tried several window functions with no success:

> partition by date_purchase

> range between interval '90 days' preceding and current row

So far I can't get to calculate correctly the number for each date.

Comment: But can you do it for every given day? How can that be done? Thanks.

Comment: hi. generally if you write a dbfiddle(https://dbfiddle.uk/btGcOH30)  to demo what's the expect result, more people willing to help to solve the problem.

Comment: Updated the original post.

Comment: Providing expected results without the corresponding input data is pretty useless. Additionally, post a couple things you have tried. It is generally understood within the community that they will not give the desired output - if it worked you would not be asking - but it gives an idea of your thinking which could be essentially correct.  You would benefit from speeding a few minuets to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/) and to review [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Window function doesn't seem to be relevant here because there is no relationship between the rows of the same window. A simple query or a self-join query should provide the expected result.

Assuming that `client_id` and `date_purchase` are two columns of `my_table` :

**1. Query for a given date `reference_date` :**

```
SELECT a.reference_date AS date_purchase, count(*) AS number_of_customers
FROM ( SELECT reference_date , client_id
         FROM my_table
        WHERE date_purchase <= reference_date AND date_purchase >= reference_date - INTERVAL '90 days'
        GROUP BY client_id
       HAVING count(*) >= 2
     ) AS a
```

**2. Query for a given interval of dates `reference_date` => `reference_date + INTERVAL '20 days'` :**

```
SELECT a.date AS date_purchase, count(*) AS number_of_customers
FROM ( SELECT ref.date, t.client_id
         FROM my_table AS t
        INNER JOIN generate_series(reference_date, reference_date + INTERVAL '20 days', '1 day') AS ref(date)
           ON t.date_purchase <= ref.date AND t.date_purchase >= ref.date - INTERVAL '90 days'
        GROUP BY ref.date, t.client_id
       HAVING count(*) >= 2
     ) AS a
 GROUP BY a.date
 ORDER BY a.date
```

**3. Query for all the date_purchase in `mytable` :**

```
SELECT a.date AS date_purchase, count(*) AS number_of_customers
FROM ( SELECT ref.date, t.client_id
         FROM my_table AS t
        INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT date_purchase AS date FROM my_table) AS ref
           ON t.date_purchase <= ref.date AND t.date_purchase >= ref.date - INTERVAL '90 days'
        GROUP BY ref.date, t.client_id
       HAVING count(*) >= 2
     ) AS a
 GROUP BY a.date
 ORDER BY a.date
```

Comment: Hi Edouard, thanks for your help. Unfortunately the condition `HAVING count >= 2` returns an error: `column count does not exist`. 
Apparently HAVING does not support any aggregation functions.

Comment: The error indicates that the column alias "count" is not recognized in the HAVING clause. Try again with `HAVING count(*) >=2` instead of `HAVING count >=2`